# How can a Google Drive file not have "any content stored on Drive"?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have a Google Form that logs all of its responses in a Google SpreadSheet I own on my Google Drive Account. The SpreadSheet of responses shows up in the "My Drive" section of Google Drive when accessed on a computer.

I'm currently writing an Android application that downloads that SpreadSheet and parses it for certain data.

I'm at the point where I've found the File and I'm able to get the File's Title, Description, and ExportLinks. However, when I try to get the File's DownloadUrl, I get a NullPointerException.

According to this part of the https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads API ("file.getDownloadUrl())"), if there is no download url, the "The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive"

How can a SpreadSheet on my Drive with over 100 responses not have any content stored on Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content here refers to binary content.  Google Spreadsheets (and the other Google Docs types) are not stored as binary content.  You can get it in a binary format like csv using the ExportLinks.  Alternatively, you can use the Spreadsheet-specific APIs like app script to interact with the spreadsheet contents.

Comment: Yes! You're right. I wish Google made it more clear that Google Sheets had its own completely different API.

Comment: It's not quite true to say Spreadsheets have a completely different API. The Drive API is about uploading/downloading entire files, which could be spreadsheets, documents, presentations, your own files, etc. It just so happens that Spreadsheets has an *additional* api which allows you to access it at row/cell level.